# Sending json file in curl and receiving it in R using plumber

Tags: r, json, plumber

I need to send a json file with multiple values and receive it in R using plumber, ive tried this but it doesnt seem to work,

```
library("rjson")
#install.packages("rjson")
#* @get /predict
#* @post /predict
function(predict) {
  # Load the package required to read JSON files.
  library("rjson")
  # Give the input file name to the function.
  result <- fromJSON(file = "input_v3.json")
  print(result)
  result <- as.data.frame(result)
  write.table(result, file="testing_v3_xyz.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE, append = T)
}


The curl command i used is curl -F data=@input_v3.json http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8000/predict
```

I need to send it a an ip address that is Rstudio in Desktop running on aws

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`plumber` unpacks JSON transparently if you send it in via `--data`:

```
library(plumber)

#* parse JSON
#* @param a  a vector
#* @param b  a vector
#* @get /predict
#* @post /predict
function(a, b) {
  result <- data.frame(a = as.numeric(a), b = as.numeric(b))
  write.table(result, file="testing_v3_xyz.csv", sep=",",
              row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE, append = T)
}
```

Running this API locally I get:

```
$ cat foo.json 
{ "a":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8" ], "b":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8" ] }
$ curl --data @foo.json  http://localhost:8414/predict
{}
$ cat ~/learning/stackoverflow/testing_v3_xyz.csv 
"a","b"
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
5,5
6,6
7,7
8,8
```

If the top level of the JSON is an array as opposed to an object, you cannot use named parameters to get the data into the function. However, you can use `req$postBody` to access the posted content:

```
library(plumber)

#* parse JSON
#* @param req  the request object
#* @get /predict
#* @post /predict
function(req) {
  result <- as.data.frame(lapply(jsonlite::fromJSON(req$postBody), unlist))
  write.table(result, file="testing_v3_xyz.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE, append = T)
}
```

For me this works for sample data like this:

```
[
  { "a":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8" ],
    "b":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8" ] },
  { "a":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8" ], 
    "b":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8" ] }
]
```

Comment: { 
   "a":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8" ],
   "b":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8" ]
} Its in this format

Comment: @Aditya Ok, I have updated my answer to reflect this data structure.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! I worked it out from your previous answer, this is exactly what i did! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Just one more thing, if i had data in this format, {
{ 
   "a":"1",
   "b":"1"
},

{ 
   "a":"1",
   "b":"1"
}
} How do i get it to write in a csv file row by row? like first a,b in one row, then the next in another?

Comment: @Aditya that's not a legal JSON structure, since elements within curly braces must be named. Do you mean `[ { "a":"1", "b":"1" }, { "a":"1", "b":"1" } ]`?

Comment: Yes sorry, like that!

Comment: Essentially sending multiple data in this format instead of the one i specified earlier.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: how does this work with the swagger interface?  when i run the R plumber it opens up the swagger interface

Comment: @ElChapo It works just the same. When I run the plumber API from RStudio the swagger API opened at `http://127.0.0.1:7338/__swagger__/`. So I only have to connect to  `http://127.0.0.1:7338/predict` using `curl`.

Comment: If using curl in powershell, use quotes for --data parameter value:
 curl --data '@foo.json'  http://localhost:8414/predict