# Receive csv using plumber through a POST request

Tags: r, plumber

I am looking to send a csv file to a database as someone posts the file using their `VBA` code (`VBA` has a 80 character [limit](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/power-query-specifications-and-limits-5fb2807c-1b16-4257-aa5b-6793f051a9f4) for their api calls, so they need to upload a csv to the server for me to parse and check)

To do this, I aim to use `plumber` and a `POST` request. My knowledge is a bit limited on how to structure the api to do this. Below is a rough example of how I see it happening. Is this even possible to do with `plumber`?

```
# api_main.R

library(plumber)

#* @awesomeAPI Simple API to upload csv

#* Return status on received csv
#* @param req
#* @post /upload
function(req) {
  df <- read.csv(req$body)
  if(all(c("A", "B", "C", "D") %in% names(df))){
    return(data.frame(msg = "Not all columns available", status = 418))
  } else {
    # upload data to DB here
    return(data.frame(msg = "OK", status = 200))
  }
}
```

Start the service:

```
plumber::plumb("api_main.R")$run(port = 5762)
```

Comment: Should work with `req$postBody` c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51945300/8416610

Comment: You probably need to convert `req$postBody` from json format to normal.