# Read local csv in plumber API

Tags: r, plumber

I want to read and process a csv file by R using plumber.

So far I found an ongoing discussion regarding file uploads in plumber on [GitHub](https://github.com/trestletech/plumber/pull/77) (though regarding binary files) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51945300/9220442) SO answer (transforming JSON file), both supposing the use of `postBody`.

I therefore started with this endpoint:

```r
library(plumber)

#* parse csv file
#* @param req  the request object
#* @post /file
function(req) {
  result <- req$postBody
  return(result)
})
```

When testing the endpoint using `httr`, I can read the file as JSON list but fail processing the data in the next step.

```r
upload_csv <- httr::upload_file("file.csv")
resp <- httr::POST(
  url = url,
  path = "echo",
  body = upload_csv
)
httr::content(resp)
```

Also, testing the endpoint yields two warnings

```r
Warning in if (stri_startswith_fixed(body, "{")) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Warning in if (stri_startswith_fixed(qs, "?")) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Rook` package for that

```
library(plumber)
library(Rook)

#* parse csv file
#* @param req the request object
#* @post /file
function(req) {
  file <- Rook::Multipart$parse(req)$req$tempfile
  result <- read.csv(file)
  result
}
```

The warnings are still there using the current CRAN version of the package, but are removed in the github version (see [here](https://github.com/rstudio/plumber/issues/270) for more info).